# Comparison of range objects

Tags: python, range, magic-methods

The range class contains the special function `__lt__`, however the following happens if I try to compare two range objects:

```
print(range(1) < range(2))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-93fed8a0f282> in <module>
----> 1 print(range(1) < range(2))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'range'
```

Why is "<" not supported ?

Comment: What do you want to check? Do you want to check which range has more element?

Comment: What would comparison even *mean*, here?  Keep in mind that a `range` object is specified by three values (start, stop, and step) - how would you rank `range(0,10,2)` with `range(1,9)`, for example?

Comment: Because the implementers decided not to support it. How would you define such an operation?

Comment: Okay, so even `__lt__` appears in `dir(range(1))`, range objects are not comparable via < ? I guess I just don't understand special functions yet.

Comment: As for why it is not supported, see comments above. As for what `__lt__` does: `range.__lt__(range(3), range(4))` produces `NotImplemented` (same with other magic methods that are implemented as slot wrappers).